# (The) Owls Are Not What They Seem

Tags: phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning, definite-article, generic-noun-phrases

"The Owls Are Not What They Seem" vs "Owls Are Not What They Seem".

This is a popular statement from Twin Peaks TV series, but is there any difference if you put "The" at the beginning or not?

Comment: Thank you for your question, and welcome to ELL! Please take a few minutes to review our [tour](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](http://ell.stackexchange.com/help) pages. Before asking a question, you should always use the _Search Q&A_ box to see if your question has already been asked. We hope you will ask more questions!

Comment: I disagree that it's a duplicate. It's not confusion about articles, its confusion about subject.

Comment: +1 One of my favorite series. Cooper : "Everyday, give you one present. A cup of strong joe" :)

Comment: I am voting to re-open this question because it's about definite article/no article, not about definite article/indefinite article. I think that the OP needs to provide more information though: never having seen "Twin Peaks", I don't know whether the statement is about owls in general or a specific group of owls that features in the series.

Comment: As a Twin Peaks (series 1) fan, I can say that the phrase refers to the owls in the Ghostwood forest, not all owls. Thus, the *the* is mandatory for people to get the reference.

Answer (score 3):

The statement from *Twin Peaks* includes the definite article:

> COOPER: Where do you come from?
>
> THE GIANT: The question is, where have you gone? The first thing I will tell you is: There’s a man in a smiling bag.
>
> COOPER: A man in a smiling bag…
>
> THE GIANT: The second thing is: **The owls are not what they seem.** The third thing is: Without chemicals, he points.

(Cited from *[The Little White Mask Blog](https://garmonblogzia.wordpress.com/tag/the-owls-are-not-what-they-seem/)*.)

There is a difference in making a generic reference (talking about owls in general) and an existential reference (talking about a set of owls that exists).

The use of a definite noun phrase with a  plural count  noun  is not used for making a generic reference, that is: it is not used to talk  about owls in general, owls as a species, or about  the typical owl.

When you have a noun phrase that consists of a plural count noun, you can only be talking about some specific owls that *exist* somewhere. They could exist only in one's dreams,   but they exist.

In addition, using  *the owls* in the sentence means that the Giant assumes that his hearer, Cooper, can or will be able to identify *which owls* he is talking about.

(For more information, see Lawler on  [generic noun phrases](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html).)

Answer (score 2):

"The owls" refer to the owls at Twin Peaks. If you just say "owls" it sounds like you're talking about owls in general.